# How can I derive one css style form antoher

Tags: css

I have two styles defined like so in my css file:

```
.open_in_new {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: mat-color($teal, 500);
}

.open_in_new_disabled {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: mat-color($grey, 500);
}
```

So, I could use either of these in my html, e.g.:

```
<mat-icon class="open_in_new_disabled">open_in_new</mat-icon>
```

Is there any way to remove the redundancy in my style declarations? I am defining font-size: 18px and margin-top: 5px twice over.

Is there a way to declare .open_in_new_disabled as having all of the styles of .open_in_new excepting for a different colour?

Comment: With a CSS preprocessor, you could "include" the declarations from the first rule, into the second. You could also simply give the HTML element more than one class - `class="open_in_new open_in_new_disabled"` - then your `.open_in_new_disabled` rule will have to specify _only_ the different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
.open_in_new,
.open_in_new_disabled {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.open_in_new {
  color: mat-color($teal, 500);
}

.open_in_new_disabled {
  color: mat-color($grey, 500);
}
```

This (the first CSS ruleset) is called **grouping**, and you can read more about it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#grouping).

The other option is to use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). For example:

```
[class*="open_in_new"] {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.open_in_new {
  color: mat-color($teal, 500);
}

.open_in_new_disabled {
  color: mat-color($grey, 500);
}
```

The attribute selector (class, in this case) uses a partial match based on the class name. It says, "Match every element with the class name which contains `open_in_new`."

Comment: Thanks to you both for your answers. Am learning much by following them up. I went with grouping in my case.